# Can I uninstall the @....... fonts without damaging my computer?

Tags: fonts, uninstall

Just curious if I would  have problems with my computer if I were to uninstall the various @.... fonts?  For example, @arial unicode ms, @batang, @dotum, @kaiti, @microsoft...., or the various microsoft... fonts, like microsoft jhenghei, microsoft yahei, etc. It may seem petty, but I'm a scrapbooker and I use a multitude of fonts and these "get in my way", for lack of a better explanation.  I never use them (that I know of...unless they run in the background).  So I'm asking here.  Thanks.  Carla

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only makes sense when you restore fonts from the old-tuned system, but even in this case the fonts are not deleted, and changed the link in the registry that points to a folder of fonts.

The short answer is - yes, you can get problems. Addition to it - a lot of space you do not win, because system fonts are restored, but the normal setting them possible - no. Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know, but you can simply [prevent a font from showing up in programs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Change-your-font-settings).

1. Open Fonts from the Control Panel, by clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Fonts.
2. Select a font, and then click Show or Hide

Alternatively, go to `C:\Windows\Fonts` in Windows Explorer, click or right-click a font and choose **Hide**.
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is true, but they're still "on" the computer and therefore still show up in my font viewer program.  Alas, doesn't help, but thanks for the info.

Comment: @MamaCoop Darn, I saw the caveat that not all programs respect the setting, but hoped yours would not be one of them; they're not supposed to show up. There's always the user feedback option. I was the original +1–I'm now wondering the answer to your question despite the accepted answer, as it stands–but left this here because I think it could be helpful for some.

Comment: @MamaCoop Maybe this helps? http://i.stack.imgur.com/5SRUL.png

Comment: Because it IS helpful.  I tried it and hoped it would work as well.  Didn't know about that caveat, but if it works with a given program, good info to keep on the thread.  Thanks!